# Having difficulty in getting the the position of markers in X and Y on google map?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 36.80, longitude: 10.18, zoom: 2.0)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
mapView.delegate = self
view = mapView

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.80, longitude: 10.18)
marker.title = "Tunis"
marker.snippet = "Tunisia"
marker.map = mapView
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.127)
let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
london.title = "London"
london.map = mapView
```

These are the markers I have and on clicking on it `didtapMarker` delegate method gets called in that I want to get `x`, `y` value of marker in order to create a view which states about some info of that particular marker. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use [info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#add_an_info_window)?

Comment: Still if you want to convert `coordinates` to `CGPoint` you can use `var point = mapView.projection.point(for: marker.position)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mapView:didTapMarker: is a delegate function called after a marker has been tapped. So in order to get the value of x and y, you need to do this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    print(marker.position.latitude)  //will print the x value or lat
    print(marker.position.longitude) //will print the y value or lng

    return false
}
```

Note that the marker has "position" property, "position" being the coordinate pair.

Please see reference for [didTap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p) and [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker).

You can use the value of x and y to get some information of the marker by [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_geocoder).

Or you can use an [info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker) to display information to the user when you tap on a marker.